# Specific commit version in composer.json produce strange require

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to make working an old PHP source code. `composer.json` contains:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "v2.2.4",
        [...]
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "v1.3.1",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures" : "dev-master#b4a135c",
        [...]
```

But when I run `php composer.phar install` I got:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/data-fixtures dev-master#b4a135c -> satisfiable by doctrine/data-fixtures[dev-master].
    - doctrine/data-fixtures dev-master requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (5.6.37) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

`doctrine/data-fixtures` requirement for this commit is [here](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures/blob/b4a135c7db56ecc4602b54a2184368f440cac33e/composer.json).

Why composer is talking about php `^7.1`? How really use version `b4a135c` of this package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using such constraint, requirements are taken from branch. So for `dev-master#b4a135c` requirements are checked for `master` branch, so this is the source of `^7.1` requirement.

Quick workaround would be to use different branch:

```
"doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.x-dev#b4a135c",
```

But you should really fix it and use real constraints and releases - pointing to specified commit is basically a hack and should be avoided. Relying on it in a long term probably will give some problems at some point. This limitation and possible problems are [documented](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#i-have-locked-a-dependency-to-a-specific-commit-but-get-unexpected-results-):

> While this is convenient at times, it should not be how you use packages in the long term because it comes with a technical limitation. The composer.json metadata will still be read from the branch name you specify before the hash. Because of that in some cases it will not be a practical workaround, and you should always try to switch to tagged releases as soon as you can.